# p5.js sound: How to remove individual cues with removeCue()

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, p5.js

The p5.js sound library documentation says that removeCue() can be used to cancel cued events. It says it takes an ID input that is returned from addCue().

When I invoke addCue and store the result to a variable it does not return an ID. It returns NaN.

The image below is a code example I wrote using the p5.js code editor.

How do I get the id ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found the issue.

Its an issue with the library https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/lib/addons/p5.sound.js

look at this link https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/lib/addons/p5.sound.js#L2178

its using `var id = this._cueIDCounter++;` but `_cueIDCounter` was never defined.

so i tried to define it like the following for your code:

```
Object.defineProperty(mySound,'_cueIDCounter',{value:1,writable:true});
```

now it returned the id.

so then i tried to remove the cue with `removeCue` but to my surprise there is also an issue which is getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined`

so then i looked again at the library code and i realised on the following line https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/lib/addons/p5.sound.js#L2198 within the removeCue function there is an error the current code is

```
p5.SoundFile.prototype.removeCue = function (id) {
    var cueLength = this._cues.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cueLength; i++) {
      var cue = this._cues[i];
      if (cue.id === id) {
        this.cues.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    if (this._cues.length === 0) {
    }
};
```

but it should be using `this._cues.splice(i, 1);` instead of `this.cues.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: Do you have a an updated version of the library you can link so I can download it ? Did you submit the bug fix to them ?

Comment: i have submitted a bug fix to them here: https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/pull/298

Comment: if you want to test you can use the following sound library file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XeniousSoftware/p5.js-sound/remove-cue-fix/lib/p5.sound.js

Comment: Thanks, it's late where I am and I will tomorrow and then award the bounty

Comment: It seems to be working. It's weird nobody noticed this problem. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: You are welcome and i am happy to help. i hope you award me the bounty as promised.

Comment: It still tells me I have to wait 4 hours.